# How to call a method in a Fragment when the Activities onResume is called? (FragmentPagerAdapter)

Tags: android

I made an activity with a `FragmentPagerAdapter` and some Tabs.

When `onResume` is called (The user exits the application and enters it again) I want to update the Fragment. (Connecting to a Web Server)

My problem is when I override `onResume` in the Fragment it is also called when the User switches a Tab. I don't want that!

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried other events like "onCreate" and "onStart"?

Another option would be to save a timestamp after getting data from webserver, so every time onResume is fired you check this timestamp to determine if your data needs to be refreshed.

You can do it using:

```
long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
```